# Why can't compilers optimize-out this std::string construction?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization, clang++, stdstring

Consider the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

size_t foo(const char* cptr)
{
    if (cptr == nullptr) { return 0; }
    return strlen(cptr);
}

size_t bar()
{
    static const char* cptr { "Hello world" };
    return std::string{cptr}.length();
}

size_t baz(const char* cptr)
{
    if (cptr == nullptr) { return 0; }
    return std::string{cptr}.length();
}
```

Using GodBolt, we [can see](https://godbolt.org/g/6Unas4) that GCC 8.1 and Clang++ 6.0 can optimize-out the `std::string` in both `bar()`, but not in `baz()`. In `baz()`, while the compiler can't return a fixed value, it can definitely just run the code for checking string length, without constructing anything, or at least without completing the construction - i.e. behave similarly to `foo()`. Why does it fully construct the string?

Comment: It will be, once you use `baz` anywhere.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Not if it's in a different translation unit.

Comment: `baz("Hello world")` will output the same single instruction as `bar()`

Comment: @ricco19: Not in a different translation unit it won't.

Comment: @einpoklum It will if you have LTO. If you don't use LTO, you are asking why the compiler won't perform an optimization that's not implemented or is disabled.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: 1. Are you sure? 2. That won't help me if it's not a constant string.

Comment: Try bar with a longer string (longer than whatever the SSO size is), you'll probably get something a bit different. string's constructor is far from trivial, probably too hard to eliminate if the size is not known.

Comment: @einpoklum Like all things optimizations, you need to try it and observe. But this is a typical case that LTO is designed to for. I would bet that it does optimize it.

Comment: Looks like you have better luck if you use std::string_view, so I guess the SSO is giving troubles here.

Comment: A `std::string` determines its length **in its constructor**.  If I'm being fair, I think the question here is "Why does the optimizer not write partial constructors that omit work that isn't needed during an object's lifetime?"

Answer (score 2):

In `baz` the compiler has no idea what `cptr` points to so it has to construct a string to get it's size.

In `bar` the compiler knows what `cptr` points to `"Hello world"` so it can replace the string creation and the call to `size` with the size of the string.

Comment: Well, it "has" to, but then it could notice that the string is only used to execute the code calculating the string length. It should be able to not construct the string and just run that - the same way it does so in `foo()`.

Comment: @einpoklumI don't see why you expect `baz` to be optimized. Citing the first `foo` as an example that the optimization exists doesn't work, since you never ask for a `std::string` in `foo`. Citing `bar` also doesn't work since the input data is known and the resulting code can be seen to be totally compile-time constant. In practice, you'll find that calls to `baz` will be inlined and when possible the whole thing will be optimized to a constant, just like in `bar`.

Comment: @einpoklum _"It should be able to ... just run that"_  What is "that"?  `string::length()`?

Comment: @einpoklum But at compile time it has no idea what that string is.  If you really want it to not make a `std::string` use a `std::string_view`: https://godbolt.org/g/wVp43H

Comment: @NathanOliver: It doesn't need to have any idea what the string is, it's enough to know it isn't null to realize that it can be constructed, in which case the only thing that really needs to be run is the code for `basing_string<char>::length()`. IMHO.

Comment: @einpoklum `length()` is just `return str_size;`.  There isn't any calculation of the size of the string done there.  That is done in the the constructor for `std::string`.  So, the compiler needs to call the constructor to get the size.  In `bar` all of this can be avoided as the compiler knows the length of the string literal so it can just return that.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think this my answer, or at least - that's the obstacle; the fact that you can't just run a method's code, but you would need to decompose what the constructor does.